# Not able to install Gearman on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, gearman

I am trying to install Gearman on my Ubuntu 12.04 machine by following command

```
sudo apt-get install gearman-job-server libgearman-dev 
sudo apt-get install php-pear php5-dev
```

Above commands run properly but when I run

```
sudo pecl install gearman
```

it is giving errors as follows

```
checking whether to enable gearman support... yes, shared
found in /usr
checking for gearman_client_set_context in -lgearman... yes
checking for gearman_worker_set_server_option in -lgearman... yes
checking for gearman_job_error in -lgearman... no
configure: error: libgearman version 1.1.0 or later required
ERROR: `/tmp/pear/temp/gearman/configure' failed
```

I am not able to find how to install it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your repository there is old version of gearman. You need do download source of the latest version (at least 1.1.0)from http://www.gearman.org/ compile and install it. Then installation php module with pecl will go smoothly.  I had similar problem on centos.

Comment: I downloaded gearmand from https://launchpad.net/gearmand   and  ./configure it but it is giving error as  "configure: error: cannot find Boost headers version >= 1.39.0"

Comment: You need to install some additional software needed in compilation proccess linux headers gcc ... etc. On centos I install this software to make compilation gearman succesful : gcc gcc-c++ mysql mysql-devel boost-devel libevent libevent-devel

Comment: Thank you, I installed new version of gearman 1.1.5 with its dependancies and installed php module and worked perfectly.

Answer (score 11):

Another option is to install libgearman-dev from the gearman PPA:

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gearman-developers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
```

Assuming you've already installed libgearman-dev and gearman-job-server, all you have to do is:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

To upgrade gearman, then simply run pecl again and it should work this time:

```
sudo pecl install gearman
```

Comment: Best way to do it.

Answer (score 3):

You can try installing an older version of gearman pecl extension. For e.g. latest version on Ubuntu 12.10 install failed. However, specifying bit earlier version worked fine:

```
pecl install gearman-1.0.3
```

You can find list of available versions on http://pecl.php.net/package/gearman